# fgetcsv utf8 and apostrophe

Tags: php, utf-8, fgetcsv

im getting a weird behavior with this code

```
        foreach ($files as $key => $error) {  
            if ($error == UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {  

                $name = $_FILES["excelFiles"]["name"][$key];  


                $handle = fopen($_FILES["excelFiles"]["tmp_name"][$key], "r"); 

                while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
                    print_r($data);
                    echo "\r\n";
                }
                fclose($handle);

            }}
```

the thing is that hebrew strings that have an apostrophe get clipped (just vanishes in the thin air)

this is one row result for example :

```
Array
(
    [0] => '
    [1] => אני לא רעבה, תודה
)
```

Answer (score 2):

That's because [`fgetcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php) expects the file to be encoded in whatever encoding your current locale uses:

> Note:
>
> Locale setting is taken into account by this function. If LANG is e.g.
>   en_US.UTF-8, files in one-byte encoding are read wrong by this
>   function.

This is what happens in your case as well.

To solve this problem you must do one of the following:

- set the locale to one that matches the encoding of your input file, if such a locale is available on your platform and the encoding is known
- constrain the valid encoding of the input file, making only the locale-compatible encoding legal
- load the file and pre-process it by converting its encoding to one that matches the locale, and then reading the data either with [`str_getcsv`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php) or by pointing to `fgetcsv` to a [memory stream](http://php.net/manual/en/wrappers.php.php) (see `php://memory` and `php://temp`) with the converted data